# Have section headers be dependent upon recto vs verso pages

Tags: sectioning, memoir

Would it be a typographical abomination to have section headers be mirrored of the verso pages on the vecto pages? ie, if the verso page looks like:

Verso:
1.1 Some header

Then,
Recto:
      Some header 1.2

And, if not? How can it be done?

btw, using memoir.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The package commonly used for this is `fancyhdr`.

Comment: @Teepeemm The `memoir` class provides its own methods for setting headers. It's not the best idea to use `fancyhdr` with `memoir`. See daleif's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not really, it is your choice, might just be confusing to the user if you also have chapters.

Here is how the default headings adds its code to the headers

if two side:

```
\makeatletter
\makepsmarks{headings}{%
      \createmark{chapter}{left}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{. \ }
      \createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
      \createplainmark{toc}{both}{\contentsname}
      \createplainmark{lof}{both}{\listfigurename}
      \createplainmark{lot}{both}{\listtablename}
      \createplainmark{bib}{both}{\bibname}
      \createplainmark{index}{both}{\indexname}
      \createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}
    }
\makeatother
```

if one page:

```
\makeatletter
    \makepsmarks{headings}{%
      \createmark{chapter}{right}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{. \ }
      \createplainmark{toc}{right}{\contentsname}
      \createplainmark{lof}{right}{\listfigurename}
      \createplainmark{lot}{right}{\listtablename}
      \createplainmark{bib}{right}{\bibname}
      \createplainmark{index}{right}{\indexname}
      \createplainmark{glossary}{right}{\glossaryname}
    }
\makeatother
```

Remember to activate `headings` afterwards:

```
\pagestyle{headings}
```

For the `\createmark` commands, the second argument can be `left`, `right` and `both`. Choose your pick